# Trying to install Virtual Treeview for Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, installation, virtualtreeview

Found trunk here:
http://virtual-treeview.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

Downloaded files... Worked through some errors with search paths 
(VirtualTreesD could not locate required package "dclstd" - it was in lib/win32/release, added it to library Delphi paths)

When I try build all I get following errors:

> [DCC Fatal Error] VirtualTreesR.dpk(29): E2225 Never-build package 'dclstd' must be recompiled
>   [DCC Fatal Error] VirtualTreesD.dpk(35): E2202 Required package 'VirtualTreesR' not found

Comment: You must first compile the runtime package (the one with `R` in the end of the `dpk` filename) and then you can install the designtime package (`D` in the end)...

Comment: I have already tried building runtime packages, that works fine! :)
But if I try "build all" or build the designtime package, I get the errors :(

Comment: Check your library paths, PATH, and DCP and BPL folders for other copies of Virtual Tree View source code, BPL or DCP files.

Comment: I got it working. (See below.) Not really entirely sure why what I did worked. But I think a path somehow was wrong in the project groups file... But if noone else has had that problem, the fault points to me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The trunk version of VirtualTreesR](http://virtual-treeview.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Packages/Delphi%20XE2/VirtualTreesR.dpk) does not require dclstd. The error message you report says it does, so it looks like you erroneously added dclstd to the run-time package's list of required packages. Revert that change. The run-time package should *not* require dclstd, which is a design-time package. It should require only vcl and vclx.

Comment: Well, this is the "requires" of VirtualTreesR: vcl, vclx; I can build that fine when I build it alone. But the moment I build design time package I get above error message. (Which I agree is odd. Not sure why it reports VirtualTreesR since that does *not* require dclstd) Hmmm... I will try again opening he dpk individually instead of using the projetc group.

Comment: Okay, I now tried install from .dpk without them sharing the same project group. Maybe somehow the paths had gotten slightly wrong in the project group or, well, to be honest, I don't know. But first opening the runtime dpk, building it, opening the designtime dpk and then installing it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change target platform in project's group from Windows 64 to 32.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler try search dclstd.dcp file, this file location is for ej. win 32 in debug "lib\win32\debug".

**Fix:** in the `tool/option/delphi option/library` add `$(BDSLIB)\$(Platform)\release` and `$(BDSLIB)\$(Platform)\debug`

Comment: This is wrong, even if you might be on the right track. You should instead use a single `$(BDSLIB)\$(PLATFORM)\$(TARGET)` instead of adding two separate entries for Release and Debug. (And it shouldn't be looking for dclstd.dcp anyway, because it shouldn't require it - see Rob's answer above.)